# RFC 3447(pkcs#1 v2.1): Is it implemented in Openssl ? If so from which version?

Tags: openssl, pkcs#1

Im having trouble hunting down documentation which mentions whether or not RFC 3447 is implemented in openssl.

I have generated some test vectors for RSA-OAEP encryption using openssl 1.0.0.
When I checked the openssl documentation i see that it mentions EME-OAEP as defined in PKCS #1 v2.0.
source:-http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html.

But when i have given these test vectors to one of my clients, they happen to say that the vectors are only compatible with version 2.1 not 2.0.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked that even though the documentation mentions as EME-OAEP v2.0 as being implemented, but it's not so.

File:- rsa_oaep.c

In ver 2.0 
EM = maskedSeed || maskedDB

In ver 2.1
EM = 0x00 || maskedSeed || maskedDB.

And hence i was able to conclude that almost from the beginning versions of openssl, its always been 2.1 NOT 2.0.

Comment: In 2.0 EM has length k-1 octets, and in 2.1 it has length k octets but the first is 0 and the remaining k-1 are the same as in 2.0; when bigendianly converted to a number by OS2IP this 'difference' vanishes and the results are interoperable. See (newer, cross) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87249/rsa-pkcs1-oaep-padding-schema-padding-0-for-first-octet and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40032/why-did-oaep-change-from-pkcs1-v2-0-and-v2-1