# OpenSSL implements PKCS#1 v2.1?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, rsa, rfc, pkcs#1

I'm using OpenSSL to do a encryption module for my project. I need a RSA PKCS#1 v2.1 implementation. How can I check if OpenSSL implements PKCS#1 v2.1?

Some people says that is implemented:

[RFC 3447(pkcs#1 v2.1): Is it implemented in Openssl ? If so from which version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317058/rfc-3447pkcs1-v2-1-is-it-implemented-in-openssl-if-so-from-which-version)

But in the documentation is PKCS#1 v2.0.

So, is it implemented? If not, where can I found a library with PKCS#1 v2.1?

Comment: Is your question only RSAES-OAEP, or the much more important difference between 2.0 and 2.1 namely RSASSA-PSS? The difference between 2.0 and 2.1 for OAEP is only notation, the actual encryption and decryption operation is exactly the same -- work it out for yourself.

Comment: I think PKCS#1 v2.1 (or maybe v2.0) added RSA multi-primes, where 3 or more primes could be used for a modulus (traditional RSA uses 2 primes, `p` and `q`). I don't believe OpenSSL provides them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that your requirements are not that sensible.

The PKCS#1 standards define various algorithms that may be used. They also provide names for them such as RSAES-OAEP and RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 (which is the original encryption scheme introduced in PKCS#1 v1.5). These schemes are fully compatible with the schemes described in PKCS#1 v2.0.

Fortunately for you you should be able to use OpenSSL without issue. It's very unlikely to fail. But first you need to know the algorithm and possible algorithm parameters (for OAEP / MGF1) you should be using.

So try it out and come back if it *does* fail.